# drawBitmap low performance on SurfaceView game thread (android)

Tags: android, performance, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I am drawing set of images on SurfaceView canvas. doDraw is called by game loop thread after getting surfaceHolder. The issue is frames per second (FPS) is really low when number of images drawn on canvas is large. This is because of drawBitmap is slow.

**Test Setup**

clusters arraylist has 400 small images (cluster.Picture). Time difference is the measured parameter to run drawBitmap loop. To compare I replaced drawBitmap with drawRect and also commented out drawBitmap leaving the loop empty body.
Device used for testing
https://www.optus.com.au/shop/prepaidmobile/lg/leon

**Test Result**  (milliseconds)

1. drawBitmap 400 loop - Average: 25.5, MIN: 14 , MAX: 37
2. drawRect 400 loop   - Average: 8.6, MIN: 5 , MAX: 21
3. Nothing 400 loop    - Average: 1.3, MIN: 0 , MAX: 10

The time above only measures portion of logic. Total game loop would take close to 40 ms. This means FPS is really low. Even for 100 loop, it takes 18 ms just to draw bitmaps.

I tried setting getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888), setFixedSize(screenSize.x , screenSize.y) and zorder as well as setting bitmap configurations to RGBA_8888. In addition I tried setting high priority using setPriority of game thread.

**I am not sure what else I can do. How can I improve performance of my game loop and FPS.**

```
    public List<PCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<PCluster>();

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    try {
        if (canvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(backColor);
        if (waitTillLoad) {
            return;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    final int savedState = canvas.save();
    try {

        minX = (int) (((viewWidth / mScaleFactor) - Gen.screenSizeWidth) / 2) * Utils.VIEW_SIZE;
        minY = (int) (((viewHeight / mScaleFactor) - Gen.screenSizeHeight) / 2) * Utils.VIEW_SIZE;

        if (mPosX > maxX) {
            mPosX = maxX;
        }
        if (mPosX < minX) {
            mPosX = minX;
        }
        if (mPosY > maxY) {
            mPosY = maxY;
        }
        if (mPosY < minY) {
            mPosY = minY;
        }


        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (!showBackground) {

            for (PCluster cluster : clusters) {
                if (cluster.isVisible) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(cluster.Picture, cluster.BoardLocation.left,
                            cluster.BoardLocation.top, null);
                }
            }
            Log.d("myApp", "   " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to improve performance some what using PorterDuff SRC_OVER paint object. This is probably because less calculations when transparent images are drawn on top of each other. Also make sure to add dithering and anti-aliasing to the paint.

```
canvasPaint = new Paint();
canvasPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER )); 

canvas.drawBitmap(cluster.Picture, cluster.BoardLocation.left,
                            cluster.BoardLocation.top, canvasPaint );
```